# How to search bybvalue in a kv database?

Tags: database, nosql

I want to use a kv database, but need to search by value, because each record must has unique uuid and (x,y,z) coordinate and some other raw binary data, I need to query by (x,y,z) often, but (x,y,z) can be changing very quickly (about per 0.1 second).
Which kv storage engine should I use? Or should I use SQL database instead? (It must be embedded and single-disk-file).

Comment: What do you expect to find via (x,y,z)? uuid of object?

Comment: Read about Sqlite LSM Extension.